# Making app with Ionic. Why do I need PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework, html-framework-7

I'm a web developer curious about these hybrid (or native?) apps I can build with HTML5 + CSS. So I decided to try building one.

So I'm totally new into this. (And also not comfortable with CLI.)

**At first**, I searched how to do, and found PhoneGap that can convert the HTML5 + CSS to an mobile app. Seems simply.

**Then I needed a framework**, and found Mobile Angular JS.

**I started to build my app.** But problems occurs when the app worked fine in desktop browser but couldn't load templates in ngview on the mobile app. That made me wonder if Mobile Angular JS maybe wasn't the perfect match for PhoneGap.

So I searched for what frameworks is best compatible with PhoneGap and found that Ionic would be that. But when I read about it in their Docs it makes me confused. It seems like Ionic have their own building program that makes my HTML to a working mobile app.

**So, why is Ionic perfect with PhoneGap**, when you already have the PhoneGap-functionality with Ionic?

I'm confused.

**Edit:**

After a several hours of further reading and taking in more comments, I think I can be pretty confident establish that PhoneGap isn't needed for Ionic. And Ionic isn't the best framework for testing PhoneGap.

It seems more easy with Framework7. PhoneGap says it's just to clone the Framework7 `dist` content into PhoneGap's `www` folder. http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/30/framework7/

But I'm a little worried, do I have to do  that clone every time I want to test?

Perhaps I ends up with jQuery Mobile anyway...

Comment: hi, if you want to build a hybrid mobile app then ionic, cordova and angularjs is enough no need to go for phoneGap.

Answer (score 5):

Ionic uses Cordova to [package up HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into multi-platform native apps](http://blog.ionic.io/where-does-the-ionic-framework-fit-in/), but also provides extra features.

[Ionic uses Cordova proper at the core, we do not use PhoneGap at all.... PhoneGap is Adobe's productized version and ecosystem on top of Cordova.](http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-cordova-phonegap/)

Ionic Angular components are designed and tested with mobile in mind.

Extra services like Ionic Cloud that integrate features such as push notification, deployments, native app packaging, user authentication, analytics and a realtime database has been announced.

PhoneGap promote their main features as [our command line interface, the PhoneGap Desktop app, the PhoneGap Developer app, and PhoneGap Build](http://phonegap.com/products/)

PhoneGap features may work with Ionic, perhaps with tweaking required, whereas Ionic features are built to work together.

Comment: But does PhoneGap make anything better in any way? The build process easier? Can I skip some steps here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html with PhoneGap instead?

Comment: PhoneGap and Ionic both provide cloud building services, meaning not on your local computer. Which one is better would be pretty subjective. If you want to skip manually using Cordova on your machine, see here: https://ionic.io/cloud#packaging

Comment: But I'm already building an app and can test it in my browser via a link from PhoneGap OSX app. I haven't downloaded Cordova to my computer. Or is PhoneGap OSX app the equivalent to download Cordova like Ionic says I can do? So I don't need to download node.js or cordova if I already have PhoneGap? But I still need to install Ionic? What is "Ionic" then? This guide is confusing: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html. I just want a project folder to start working with...

Comment: Ionic and PhoneGap both use Cordova, but provide their own features on top. Ionic's original main feature was their Angular components built specifically for mobile, which PhoneGap does not provide.

Comment: PhoneGap App might work with an Ionic project, but you may need to make some modifications. It seems others have used PhoneGap features with Ionic before: http://devgirl.org/2014/09/08/quick-tip-testing-ionic-apps-with-the-phonegap-developer-app/

Comment: But I think PhoneGap seems nice cause I'm more comfortable with a UI rather than command lines. So the best for me would be to get a Ionic project to work with, then test and compile it with PhoneGap. But I can't see how I get an Ionic project, for example the todo blank here http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html, without Node.js and Ionic package?

Comment: RationalDev about the devgirl.org link, seems she had to go over to CLI there anyway. It seems like the search result I had in the begining of my research where I found that Ionic works great with PhoneGap, maybe was out of date result? Cause nowadays you don't need PhoneGap? Everything I did with PhoneGap is possible with Ionic's own commands if I have installed Cordova on my computer? Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128816/discussion-between-rationaldev-and-peter-westerlund).

Answer (score 1):

I think a better understanding of Ionic, what it is and why to use it will help you understand better the purpose.

I'm attaching two paragraphs from Ionic's documentation:

**What is Ionic, and where does it fit?**
Ionic is an HTML5 mobile app development framework targeted at building hybrid mobile apps. Hybrid apps are essentially small websites running in a browser shell in an app that have access to the native platform layer. Hybrid apps have many benefits over pure native apps, specifically in terms of platform support, speed of development, and access to 3rd party code.

Think of Ionic as the front-end UI framework that handles all of the look and feel and UI interactions your app needs in order to be compelling. Kind of like “Bootstrap for Native,” but with support for a broad range of common native mobile components, slick animations, and beautiful design.

Unlike a responsive framework, Ionic comes with very native-styled mobile UI elements and layouts that you’d get with a native SDK on iOS or Android but didn’t really exist before on the web. Ionic also gives you some opinionated but powerful ways to build mobile applications that eclipse existing HTML5 development frameworks.

**Since Ionic is an HTML5 framework, it needs a native wrapper like Cordova or PhoneGap in order to run as a native app. We strongly recommend using Cordova proper for your apps, and the Ionic tools will use Cordova underneath.**

**Why did we build Ionic?**
We built Ionic because we strongly believed that HTML5 would rule on mobile over time, exactly as it has on the desktop. Once desktop computers became powerful enough and browser technology had advanced enough, almost everyone was spending their computing time in the browser. And developers were overwhelmingly building web applications. With recent advancements in mobile technology, smartphones and tablets are now capable of running many of those same web applications.

With Ionic, we wanted to build an HTML5 mobile development framework that was focused on native or hybrid apps instead of mobile websites, since we felt there were great tools already for mobile website development. So Ionic apps aren’t meant to be run in a mobile browser app like Chrome or Safari, but rather the low-level browser shell like iOS’s UIWebView or Android’s WebView, **which are wrapped by tools like Cordova/PhoneGap.**

Please read more here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html

Comment: I have actually read that text before I wrote my question here on Stackoverflow. That what's make me confused. Because in the start guides on Ionic's website it seems like I have to install programs on my computer. Node.js, Cordova. How could the app work on the mobile later when it depend on programs on the computer? But Cordova is Phonegap? So if I have Phonegap, I can skip does parts in the start guide? I will think I only need the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic just provides basic structure and basic functionalities that you can use for your app to work(it provides css and javascript components like buttons,popups,dialogs,modals and many other stuffs) but to make  it a real android ,ios or windows app you need to build it as .apk or .appx or .ipa .That is where phonegap comes in.You just follow the structure of ionic framework and then build it in phonegap,your app is ready after that.

Comment: Isn't the "Configure Platform" and "Test it out" here http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html more than just a framework? It more like Ionic is a program like PhoneGap Build on my computer or PhoneGap app on my mobile?

Comment: Ionic framework can do nothing without cordova(used by phonegap as well).All those configuration and setup that you do in ionic is just for to create config.xml which is finally read by phonegap to install also dependencies to your app

Comment: I wanna make things clear. Watching this page: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html Is PhoneGap like the equivalent to the `ionic build ios --release` command? Or does PhoneGap make the build easier in any way?

Comment: seems like  ionic framework too has now started facilities to build an app or i might not have used it.But i am very sure they must be using cordova. :)